# Saved Search/ Hash Tag pulling in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

We can search for a specific term called "Saved Searches" on Twitter and hashtags in Instagram using their respective APIs. Do we have any similar functionality in LinkedIn also?

Thanks in Advance.